# onClick active tab add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on the accordion tabs here on active I want to add the class `.elementor-active` in the '.elementor-tab-title' but when I tried to add active class it is added to all '.elementor-tab-title' I also used `.siblings()` and `children()` but still not working can anyone point me in the right direction.

```js
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-content').hide();

  $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-title > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-title').addClass('elementor-active').closest().find('.elementor-active').removeClass('elementor-active');
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.elementor-accordion {
  margin: 50px;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title:last-of-type,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title a,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content {
  border-top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content:last-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font: 16px Sans-Serif;
}

.elementor-tab-title.elementor-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-accordion">
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 1</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 2</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 3</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's some changes

Just remove before adding class `$('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');`

and add class to targeted element `$(this).parent().addClass('elementor-active');`

### Edit:

If you want a toggle then you can check using `$(this).parent().hasClass('elementor-active')` if element has a class or not and take action as bellow.

```js
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-content').hide();

  $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-title > a').click(function() {
    //allPanels.slideUp();
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('elementor-active')){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('elementor-active').next().slideUp();
    } else {
     $(this).parent().addClass('elementor-active').next().slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.elementor-accordion {
  margin: 50px;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title:last-of-type,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title a,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content {
  border-top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content:last-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font: 16px Sans-Serif;
}

.elementor-tab-title.elementor-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-accordion">
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 1</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 2</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 3</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @RaviMakwana onClick active tab is visible and other tabs are getting close how can we make them as a toggle. so that other tabs are not closed automatically when one of the tabs is closed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$(this)` instead of getting element using class. you need to have knowledge about how `this` keyword works in JavaScript.

```js
    (function ($) {

        var allPanels = $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-content').hide();
        $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-title > a').click(function () {
            if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('elementor-active')) {
                allPanels.slideUp();
                allPanels.prevObject.find('.elementor-active').removeClass('elementor-active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('elementor-active')
                $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
            }
            else {
                allPanels.slideUp();
                allPanels.prevObject.find('.elementor-active').removeClass('elementor-active');
            }

            return false;
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

```css
.elementor-accordion {
  margin: 50px;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title:last-of-type,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title a,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content {
  border-top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content:last-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font: 16px Sans-Serif;
}

.elementor-tab-title.elementor-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-accordion">
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 1</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 2</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 3</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be what you're looking for. I have seperated the add and remove class for clarity.

```js
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-content').hide();

  $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-title > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $('.elementor-accordion-item > .elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('elementor-active');
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.elementor-accordion {
  margin: 50px;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title:last-of-type,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-title a,
.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content {
  border-top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.elementor-accordion .elementor-tab-content:last-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font: 16px Sans-Serif;
}

.elementor-tab-title.elementor-active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementor-accordion">
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 1</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 2</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title"><a href="">Panel 3</a></div>
    <div class="elementor-tab-content">Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</div>
  </div>

</div>
```